# What does "TGM" vs "TKG" mean from Sentinel 2 Images (Google Earth Engine)?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I extracted sentinel 2 images from Google Earth Engine using the Python API with something like this:

```
# Sentinel 2 Image Collection
s2_image_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")

filteredCollection = s2_image_collection.filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 5))
```

When I loop over the images in `filteredCollection`, I get the following `ids`:

```
COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20191002T162111_20191002T162929_T16TGM
COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20191002T162111_20191002T162929_T17TKG
COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20191005T163131_20191005T163713_T16TGM
COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20191005T163131_20191005T163713_T17TKG
...
```

I was surprised to see two images for each date. What does "T16TGM" vs "T17TKG" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Accrding to Sentinel 2 [product naming convention](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/naming-convention), the part you are interested in corresponds to the image Tile number according to the [US-MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System) naming convention.

Note that Sentinel-2 products are [a compilation of elementary granules](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/news/-/asset_publisher/Ac0d/content/sentinel-2-level-1c-product-tiling-grid-released) of fixed size, along with a single orbit.